# "Capital letter", "uppercase letter"

Tags: terminology

If you're teaching someone to read and write. What is the most common way to say... a "capital letter" or "uppercase letter". Which would be the difference between them.

Comment: In the old days, the ordinary word was _capital_, and _upper case_ was a jargon word of printers and typographers. Now that everybody is familiar with text-processing and on-line publishing, they're both in common use. There's no difference in meaning that I can find.

Answer (score 1):

In the sense of the words being used, they mean the same thing.

According to [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=capital%20letter%2C%20uppercase%20letter&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccapital%20letter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuppercase%20letter%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccapital%20letter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuppercase%20letter%3B%2Cc0), the phrase **capital letter** is far more common than the the phrase **uppercase letter** (although *uppercase letter* does get some use):

[image: capital letter versus uppercase letter]

---

In contrast, if we look at a different phrase, [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=use%20capitals%2C%20use%20uppercase&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuse%20capitals%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuse%20uppercase%3B%2Cc0) shows that **use uppercase** is (now) a little less than twice as common as **use capitals**:

[image: use uppercase versus use capitals]

---

There is no essential difference in meaning, and, given that one word is more common in one phrase, but less common in another phrase, you have to look at the particular context.

---

Note there are some different senses of both [*capital*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/capital) and [*letter*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/letter) that are unrelated to the senses used in this question, or to the main part of my answer.

Particularly in the UK, *capital* is an adjective that means *excellent* ("*A capital idea!*"). When using *letter* not in its letter-of-the-alphabet sense but in its written-letter-in-an-envelope sense, a *capital letter* could mean an *excellent letter*.

Similarly, using the sense of *capital* that applies to criminal punishment, a *capital letter* could be interpreted as a *writ of execution*.

Since the question is asking about the difference between *capital* and *uppercase*, those are not the senses under consideration. But I wanted to add it as a kind of addendum. It's also possible that the Google Ngram results, in particular the first one, could be (very partially) capturing some of these alternate senses where no context is given.

Comment: “a letter that is *excellent*, or a letter related to somebody's *execution*” — I can only speak for myself, but I strongly dispute both of those. Even if you told me that’s how you meant to use the adjective, I would say that’s unclear, and I would never arrive at that interpretation on my own. That’s what’s keeping this answer from getting at least my upvote.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish Perhaps it's because I'm exposed to British culture, where the phrase *Capital!* is used more often than in the US to express excellence. *"That's a capital idea!"* It can be used as an adjective for any noun—including letters. And in the context of the phrase (which is *not* the context of the question), a *capital letter* would not be a letter of the alphabet, but a written letter in an envelope. (Similarly, a *capital letter* in the other sense, would be a *writ of execution*.)

Comment: That’s entirely possible. I think you should include that disclaimer in your answer personally.

Comment: I meant the “British” part. Nevertheless +1

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish Ah. I have now significantly updated that part of my answer—and moved it to the bottom where it doesn't interfere with the main part of what I was trying to say. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Thanks, Jason. I'll keep your comment in mind :)